# If a com wrapper around a .net DLL uses one more dependent .net DLLs, should they be placed in GAC?

Tags: c#, gac, managed, ccw

If a managed DLL uses one or more managed DLLs, and a com wrapper is built around the managed DLL, then should all the dependent managed DLLs be placed in GAC. I am getting an "unable to find assembly..." in a similar scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out keeping assemblies in GAC is a good in case when those dlls are referenced by the COM wrapper. The .net runtime can easily locate them.